# Multiple forms but only the first one is working

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I actually have multiple forms to apply for each job in my page.

The problem is that only my first form is working : 
- When i click on the first form, i can fill my full name and email, and  i can upload files 
- On the other forms, i can fill everything but the file upload : when i click on the button, nothing is happening

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'offre_demploi' ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$i = 0;
// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<div class="container">';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<div class="col-sm-4 col-12 "><h4 id="follow'.$i.'" class = "item item'. $i .'" >'.get_field("type_demploi") . '</h4></div>';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<div class="col-sm-8 col-12 nopadding descrip">';
        echo "\n";
        echo '<h5 >'.get_field("resume").'</h5> </div> </div>';
        echo '<div class="row">';
        echo "\n";
        echo '  <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 agenceB"><br/><p>'.get_field("collaboration");
        echo '</p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong'.$i.'">
                     Postuler
                </button>
                <div class="modal fade item item'.$i.'" id="exampleModalLong'.$i.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle'.$i.'" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-header">
                                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle'.$i.'">Postuler pour '. get_field("type_demploi") .'</h5>
                                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="modal-body">';
        gravity_form('Postuler', false, false, false, null, true );
        echo ' </div>
                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> </div> ';

        echo '
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 agencenoB16 d-none d-lg-block offre nopadding3">
                '.nl2br(get_field("description")).'
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 agencenoB16 d-none d-lg-block offre nopadding3">
            '.nl2br(get_field("description2")).'
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class = "row d-block d-md-none">
            <br/>
            <div class="col">
                <a href="#suite'.$i.'" class = "navigation"><p> Lire la suite </p></a>
            </div>
            <div  class = "col no-gutters suite " id="suite'.$i.'">
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 "></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 agencenoB16 offre nopadding3">
                '.nl2br(get_field("description")).'
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-12 agencenoB16 offre nopadding3">
                '.nl2br(get_field("description2")).'
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            <br/><br/>';

        $i++;


    }

} else
{
    // no posts found
}
// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Do you have any idea why it is not working ? It was working some days ago, but i don't remember if i might have edit something that could do this ...
Ps : the $i increment is used to fill the job name automaticaly in my form

Thanks

Comment: Please for the sake of god and your future sanity, avoid writing html from PHP. Use a template engine like twig.

Comment: thanks but thats not helping me ..

Comment: What do you mean by "I can fill everything but the file upload" - what keeps you from filling these fields? What happens instead when you try to fill them?